# jquery append not working right

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a each td element containing an input tag. I wrote the following code

```
var elements = $('#booklist .ISBN_number');
```

to make an array of all of the isbn numbers contained in those input tags.

I am trying to write a jquery command to append an image to the content of those input tags. I had written

```
$(elements[index]).val().append("<img src = 'pics/green_checkmark.png'>");
```

which doesn't work. I have checked and $(element[index]).val() does have a numeric isbn value. Why can't I append to it? (I wan't to image to show up on the right of the input tag)

Comment: Hint: a better title would be "Help me understand jQuery.append()".

Comment: @LarryLustig: so what don't you change it? You have the rep...

Comment: `String`'s do not have an `append()` method.

Comment: I won't edit someone's post for manners.  I hope the OP will consider my suggestion (and perhaps adjust their broader approach to dealing with technical issues), but I'd rather leave it up to them.

Comment: I actually just tried to change it and it wont let me put the word "help" in the title. I understand why you don't like the title though, because it my misunderstanding the code, not a bug in the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `val` function returns a string of the current value of the element.

If you want to append the image after the input tag, you can use the `after` function.

```
elements.eq( index ).after( "<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png'>" );
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. I never knew about the eq() function until now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot append an image in a text input tag

You should try [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and place the image after the input.

Answer (score 0):

Because `.val()` returns a string, not a jquery object. You'd have to do something like this:

```
$(elements[index]).val( $(elements[index]).val() + "<img src = 'pics/green_checkmark.png'>") );
```

However, you can't add an image inside of an input. You'd have to add it after the input, then move it over the input with css; something like:

```
img { margin-left: -15px; }
```

Comment: You mean `$(elements[index]).val( $(elements[index]).val() + "<img src = 'pics/green_checkmark.png'>") );` ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML looks something like this:

```
<table id="booklist">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="ISBN_number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="ISBN_number" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

What you need to do is use the [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method which will append the value after the selector.

Also, if you have a jQuery object that selects more than 1 object, any method performed on that object will apply to all the objects that selector hits.

So change your code to.

```
var elements = $('#booklist .ISBN_number');
elements.after("<img src = 'pics/green_checkmark.png'>");
```

And this will give you html ala:

```
<table id="booklist">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="ISBN_number" /><img src="pics/green_checkmark.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="ISBN_number" /><img src="pics/green_checkmark.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have never made use of after() before yet. But its actually not what I need in this specific case. Here, I want to append the code after the input tag only on a condtion that is valid. Thus, I was checking each input in the table to see if it was valid and if so put a check mark. What I needed was eq() as shown in a different post here (with the use of after() as well.)